# Python/Tkinter: How to change Label widget with using Entry widget?

Tags: python, tkinter

What i wanted to do is, while typing some words in Entry widget, at the same time changing the characters that are displayed in label widget. Here are the codes:

```
import tkinter as tk


class App(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master=None):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master)

        self.entry = tk.Entry(master=self)
        self.entry.pack(side="left")

        self.var = tk.StringVar()
        self.var.set(self.entry.get)

        self.label = tk.Label(master=self)
        self.label.pack(side="left")

        self.configure_widgets()
        self.pack()

    def configure_widgets(self):
        self.label.configure(textvariable=self.var)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    example = App(master=root)
    example.mainloop()
```

Which parts i should change of the codes? Thank you in advance.

Comment: You want to display the same text in the Entry and the Label?

Comment: Yes, the problem was solved by FamousJameous' message, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both `Entry` and `Label` accept a variable as a parameter. The entry will set the variable value and the Label will get it.

```
import tkinter as tk


class App(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master=None):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master)

        self.var = tk.StringVar()

        self.entry = tk.Entry(master=self, textvariable=self.var)
        self.entry.pack(side="left")

        self.label = tk.Label(master=self, textvariable=self.var)
        self.label.pack(side="left")

        self.configure_widgets()
        self.pack()

    def configure_widgets(self):
        self.label.configure(textvariable=self.var)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    example = App(master=root)
    example.mainloop()
```